# Using N1ql to update/replace an array element and matching three conditions

Tags: sql-update, couchbase, sql++

SO update should happen when

_id is =“4617a874-9a8a-4b57-b9f6-6c0c83e4c0f8”

2._type =“AssetDef”

3.maintenance _id is matching _id = “50a0c62b-f7b2-4fba-ac51-19e0976c8760”
THEN it should update : this value **"mos_fixDate": false to mos_fixDate": true**

````
```
{
“_id”: “4617a874-9a8a-4b57-b9f6-6c0c83e4c0f8”,
“_type”: “AssetDef”,
“maintenance”: [
{
"_id": “50a0c62b-f7b2-4fba-ac51-19e0976c8760”,
“description”: “nekaj6”,
“duration”: 3,
“maintenanceName”: “nekaj6”,
"mos_fixDate": false,
“period”: 3,
“type”: “preventiveMaintenance”
},
{
“_id”: “fa022b93-c9f8-4c45-a33b-98d5c7ae74e3”,
“description”: “ma neki neki”,
“duration”: “40”,
“label”: “test 123”,
“maintenanceName”: “test 123”,
“period”: 1000,
“type”: “preventiveMaintenance”
}
]
}
````

Expecing:

````
```
{
“_id”: **“4617a874-9a8a-4b57-b9f6-6c0c83e4c0f8”** = MATCHING ,
“_type”: “**AssetDef**”, = MATCHING 
“maintenance”: [
{
**"_id": “50a0c62b-f7b2-4fba-ac51-19e0976c8760”,** = MATCHING 
“description”: “nekaj6”,
“duration”: 3,
“maintenanceName”: “nekaj6”,
"mos_fixDate": **true**,
“period”: 3,
“type”: “preventiveMaintenance”
},
{
“_id”: “fa022b93-c9f8-4c45-a33b-98d5c7ae74e3”,
“description”: “ma neki neki”,
“duration”: “40”,
“label”: “test 123”,
“maintenanceName”: “test 123”,
“period”: 1000,
“type”: “preventiveMaintenance”
}
]
}
````

I tried :

UPDATE i4c USE KEYS "maintenance"

SET maintenance[i] = {"mos_fixDate":true}

FOR i : a IN maintenance WHEN a._id="50a0c62b-f7b2-4fba-ac51-19e0976c8760" END RETURNING maintenance

AND _id = "4617a874-9a8a-4b57-b9f6-6c0c83e4c0f8"

Comment: N1ql is for couchbase not couchdb?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE `i4c` AS u
SET u.`mos_fixDate` = true
      FOR m IN u.maintenance 
         WHEN m._id = "50a0c62b-f7b2-4fba-ac51-19e0976c8760" END
WHERE u._id = "4617a874-9a8a-4b57-b9f6-6c0c83e4c0f8"
      AND u._type = "AssetDef";
```

Example 9 at https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html#update-for